# Python change a date format in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pycharm, date-format

I have a dataset containing a column "date":

```
date                     item
20.3.2010 17:08           a 
20.3.2010 11:16           b
2010-03-20 15:55:14.060   c
2010-03-21 13:56:45.077   d
```

I would like to convert all values that have format as `20.3.2010 17:08` into `2010-03-21 13:56:45.077`.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on below:

```
from datetime import datetime

INPUT_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
OUTPUT_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

datetime.strptime('20.3.2010 17:08',INPUT_FORMAT).strftime(OUTPUT_FORMAT)
#Output '2010-03-20 17:08:00.000000'
```

You could find more information in [offcial `strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

To do a 100% match with 3 digits microseconds you could use [this SO approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040177/python-datetime-round-trim-number-of-digits-in-microseconds).

Answer (score 1):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], , format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

You can find more information on `pd.to_datetime()` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), and the format string type can be [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).