# How to round a datetime variable in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I round a `datetime` variable like this one:

```
x = datetime.now()
```

which produces something like this:

```
2022-05-04 15:36:01.055696
```

to something like this?

```
2022-05-04 15:36:01.057
```

Comment: Do you have a string or a `datetime` variable? The one you show is just a string.

Comment: 1) Rounding would produce `....056`. 2) Do you really need millisecond precision for a timestamp that includes the year? I would just trim the string with `x = x[:-3]` and call it a day (pun not intended).

Comment: x is datetime.now()

Comment: Are you asking how to format the *string* so that it only shows 3 decimals of precision?  Or are you asking how to round the *value*, so it would represent `2022-05-04 15:36:01.056000`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime: Round/trim number of digits in microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040177/datetime-round-trim-number-of-digits-in-microseconds)

Comment: @High-Octane I think OP wants to modify the datetime object itself, rather than just format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to modify a `datetime` object, you can round its `.microsecond` attribute:

```py
x = datetime.now()
print(x.isoformat(' '))
# 2022-05-04 15:36:01.055696

x = x.replace(microsecond=round(x.microsecond / 1000) * 1000)
print(x.isoformat(' '))
# 2022-05-04 15:36:01.056
```

In any case (even without modifying the object and rounding the microseconds), to get the representation you want you can format it with the appropriate method:

```py
x.isoformat(' ', timespec='milliseconds')
# 2022-05-04 15:36:01.056
```

---

Note that modifying the object using `round(x.microsecond / 1000) * 1000` for the microseconds will *round* them to the closest millisecond. If you just want to *truncate* the microseconds instead, use `x.microsecond // 1000 * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the last few characters you could do:

```
print(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

The formatting str is the default which is what you are seeing in the output

Comment: You don't have to call `strftime`; `str(x)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a unix timestamp and then round the number to 3 decimal places.

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '2022-05-04 15:36:01.055696'

# Convert to datetime object
d = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Convert to rounded unix timestamp
ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(d.timestamp(), 3))

# You know have rounded datetime object, you can convert back to string with
ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

Comment: `.%f` will produce `.055000`

Comment: Just updated to remove trailing digits. @MarcoBonelli

Answer (score -1):

Pandas timestamp has a built in-function for this.
Make the timestamp a timestamp object then use [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.ht).

```
import pandas as pd

x = '2022-05-04 15:36:01.055696'
ts = pd.Timestamp(x)
ts_rounded = ts.round(freq='L')
print(ts_rounded) 2022-05-04 15:36:01.056000
```